# find: What does it mean for "-a" to have higher precedence than "-o"?

Tags: find

The man page for gnu find states:

> Please note that -a when specified implicitly (for example by two tests
>   appearing without an explicit operator between them) or explicitly  has
>   higher precedence than -o.  This means that
>   `find . -name afile -o -name bfile -print`
>   will never print afile.

I'm guessing the above expression equates to:

```
find . -name afile -o -name bfile -a -print
```

My question is, how does this expression work? and why will `afile` never be printed?

Comment: "Higher precedence" means `X -o Y -a Z` is parsed as `X -o ( Y -a Z )` rather than `(X -o Y) -a Z`.  The same way as `1 + 2 * 3 = 7`, rather than `9`.

Comment: And since `and` is somewhat [akin to multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Values), and `or` to addition, it's natural for `and` to have higher precedence.

Comment: @Sato Katsura .  that explains it well, thanks

Answer (score 3):

The `-and`/`-a` operators are the logical **AND** operator. They do not have to be specified since they are implied by the juxtaposition of two expression.

And yes, it won't print `afile` while you're using `find . -name afile -o -name bfile -a -print` since **AND** operator has a higher precedence than **OR** operator `-or`/`-o`. If you want `afile` to be printed, you have two options:

#### First Option:

As @malo mentioned, by running `find . \( -name afile -o -name bfile \) -a -print` you can have the `afile` printed since parentheses have the highest precedence in Find commands in both GNU and BSD versions.

#### Second Option:

By not passing `-print` option. So it'll be `find . -name afile -o -name bfile` and the reason is, there is nothing with higher precedence than `-o`.

Comment: This answer left me confused because there is a major part missing: If there are no "-print" actions, find implicitly surrounds the entire expression with \( ... \) -print (see top of find man page). That is why "find . -name afile -o -name bfile" finds both. But once you add "-print" anywhere, the global default now becomes to not print. That is why afile does not show up even though "-name afile" (and the entire expression) evaluates to true. Another way to fix it is this: "find . -name afile -print -o -name bfile -print".

Answer (score 1):

You should use parentheses since they have higher precedence than `-a`:

```
find . \( -name afile -o -name bfile \) -a -print
```